# Hyperref'ing definitions without having to navigate back like in wikipedia

Tags: hyperref, ntheorem, navigation

I am currently typing up lecture notes and whenever a import term comes up I place hyperref to it's definition like so:

```
\hyperref[defn:markovChain]{Markov-chain}
```

where I am using the `ntheorem` package for the theorem like environments such as `defn`.

My problem in reading and navigating the document is that whenever you click on such an reference and arrive at the definition you have to scroll through half the document to get back to the passage you were reading.

One (ambitious) idea of mine to avoid this was that one could instead of being taking a few pages back to the definition enable this definition to appear as a "pop-up" when hovering the cursor of the term, similar to how it is done in wikipedia:

[image]

Is there a way to this is in `LaTex`?

Comment: Have you looked for [`{tooltips}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tooltips?sort=MostFrequent) yet?

Comment: @AlexG No, I haven't. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: As there can be more than one link jumping to the definition, going back should be done with the tools of the pdf viewer, e.g. I get back with alt+left arrow.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But can't I display such a pop-up for every link?

Comment: Sure, I was commenting the "scroll back" description in your question.